# Laravel Can't disable Maintenance mode

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7, laravel-cache

I've put my Laravel into the maintenance mode with `php artisan down`.

No I try to disable the mode with the command from the docs (`php artisan up`) but nothing happends.

I've cleared all Laravel caches and my browser cache. What is wrong?

Comment: Remove the maintenance file in `/storage/framework`

Comment: The answers you've received are good, but do note that if you have multiple load-balanced servers, you have to run `php artisan up` on *each* of them.